# Why is Android WebView's cache counted as non-cache data by App Manager?

Tags: android, caching

In my WebView app I am doing:

```
browser.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
browser.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```

but on my test Android 4.4 device (Sony Xperia Z Ultra) if I go to Settings / Apps / my app name, the cached files are counted under "Data on device", not under "Cache".

This is a problem because (1) the "Clear data" button will also clear cookies, it is not possible to clear just the cache from this screen and (2) if the system is not recognising this cache as "Cache" then presumably it cannot automatically clear it when storage space is tight.  I can work around (1) by providing my own user interface for clearing cache, but I cannot work around (2).

Why does `setAppCachePath` to `getCacheDir` *not* result in the space taken being counted as "Cache" rather than "Data" by the app manager?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is [Chromium bug 245549](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=245549) which was fixed in end-November 2014 so probably affects all versions of Android below 6.0 (API 23).  I should probably `clearCache` in my `onDestroy` when `Integer.valueOf(Build.VERSION.SDK)<23` to stop taking up too much space on old phones.